# problem with constexpr constructor requiring constant member function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I'm having problem with my code related to the compiler requiring the member function to be constant. I'm not sure how to get it to work since i need to modify `m_data` in the get function and thus it cannot be a constant member function.

Here's the code

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename t, const size_t size, const size_t key>
class XorArray {
 public:
  // holds encrypted array data
  std::array<t, size> m_data;

  // compile-time create xor array
  __attribute__((always_inline)) constexpr XorArray(
      const std::array<t, size> &elements)
      : m_data{} {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) m_data[i] = elements[i] ^ key;
  }

  // retrive unxored data at runtime
  __attribute__((always_inline)) const t *get(){
    for (auto &element : m_data) element ^= key;

    return m_data.data();
  }
};

static constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 5> test_data = {68, 88, 66, 67, 80};

int main() {
  static constexpr auto test_data_enc =
      XorArray<uint8_t, test_data.size(), 0x5>(test_data);

      const auto test_get = test_data_enc.get();

  return 0;
}
```

The error message is

```
error: passing 'const XorArray<unsigned char, 5, 5>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

const auto test_get = test_data_enc.get();
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nrv9nT)

Comment: So, what happens when you call get twice?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the member? Can you not just return a new array/write to an array passed by non-`const` reference?

Answer (score 0):

You may compute unxored data in a local var and return it.

```
  __attribute__((always_inline)) const std::array<t, size> get() const {
    auto data = m_data;
    for (auto &element : data) element ^= key;

    return data;
  }
```

Or store the original elements and return them.

```
  std::array<t, size> m_data;
  std::array<t, size> m_elements;

  // compile-time create xor array
  __attribute__((always_inline)) constexpr XorArray(
      const std::array<t, size> &elements)
      : m_data{}, m_elements(elements) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) m_data[i] = elements[i] ^ key;
  }

  // retrive unxored data at runtime
  __attribute__((always_inline)) const t *get() const {
    return m_elements.data();
  }
```

Comment: why cant i modify the members?

Comment: Because of a constexpr object. Its members can't be modified.